# Prevent importing Angular into app.ts

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack, typescript-typings

Is there a way to not import Angular into my app.ts file? This way I do not have duplicate imports if I create more modules. I have a vendor.ts file that contains all of the imports for 3rd party packages such as Angular. I am getting this warning if I don't import Angular into the app.ts file:

> 'angular' refers to a umd global, but the current file is a module

Here is my app.ts:

```html
export let app = angular.module('app', ['app.home']);
```

I am using the following technologies:

1. Angular 1.6.9
2. @types/angular 1.6.42
3. Webpack 3

Any suggestions or solution would be great!

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to avoid multiple imports of the same module?  Webpack is smart enough to hand you the same instance of `angular` in every file you import it.  In our solution, we import `angular` in many different files within the same app.

Comment: That is good to know, I thought if I import Angular for each moduleA, moduleB, and moduleC, Webpack would include Angular 3 times.